# Interpreting symbol at the end of entries in Latin probate act book?

Tags: legal-latin, new-latin

While transcribing entries in a 16th century Latin probate act book, I have come across a symbol that commonly appears at the end of entries, and sometimes within entries:

[image: Probate Act Book example, 1596]

What does it represent? Is it a word, symbol, or form of punctuation? How is it best transcribed using a standard keyboard?

Comment: It seems almost like a really deformed and hollow [hedera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleuron_(typography)), but the use of paragraph breaks would make it redundant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be et cetera? That is often abbreviated as *e(t)c* in manuscripts: although I've not seen this exact form before, and Cappelli does not seem to have it (consulted at the University of Cologne), it looks like it could be *ec*. I've read most of the text, and *et cetera* would fit the context (although *et cetera* easily fits any context).

Comment: @Nathaniel: I've fleshed it out a bit more, explaining what I've done to 'research' it. Although unless someone finds this exact abbreviation with the exact same shape somewhere, I doubt whether much will come up... I could transcribe the whole text, but that would seem superfluous, since Harry is already doing that.

Comment: Ah, you could be right, I should have thought of that! Though why they thought it was necessary to add every time is beyond me. It might be abbreviated "[&c](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%26c.)"?

Comment: @HarryVervet: It sure might be: is that curl at the beginning how your scribe write the & sign? The scribe is probably adding *etc.* to abbreviate certain standard formulae? The entries in this document are rather standardised.

Comment: I can't specifically see any other use of & in the document, the scribe always seems to use "et" instead. Anyway I am confident your answer is correct, I have now found a couple of examples that have the same format with &c. at the end - e.g. https://books.google.com/books?id=8FQMAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA195